# Ideas for SOA Service Components

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soa

I am an undergraduate student from Mumbai University, now in my final year. The topic for our undergraduate project is "Service Oriented Architecture". As a part of this project, we are supposed to build reusable web service components, and then create a demo web application using those services.

Please suggest me some ideas for the kind of service components that would be easier to build, and then can be used in a demo web app.

Comment: There is no single answer to this question. Please make it Community Wiki and maybe it will stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some practical examples of how to build a SOA using WCF.

I would suggest you read articles by Thomas Erl and Roger Sessions, this will give you a firm handle on what SOA is all about.

[Building a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Building-Service-Orientated-Architecture)

[SOA Design Pattern](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/SOA-Design-Pattern-WCF)

[Achieving integrity in a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Achieving-Non-Functional-Requirements-for-a-Service-Oriented-Software-Platform-Integrity)

[Why your SOA should be like a VW Beetle](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Why-your-Service-Orientated-Architecture-SOA-needs-to-be-like-a-VW-Beetle)

[SOA explained for your boss](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/soa-with-wcf)

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary web service.

- Word look ups
- synonyms
- sending mp3's for pronunciation guides
- different forms of words
- usage guide

There are lots of things you could do with a dictionary web service.

Comment: We were thinking of creating components like Login Component, Captcha Component, Profile Information Component etc. Do such components fall under SOA?

Comment: @Bhushan, no. As the names indicate those are components of a system, and usually decoupling those components from the rest of the system usually leaves the component incapable of performing the expected services. SOA should be used for integrating discrete systems themselves like CRM systems, Accounting systems, Sales and Purchase order systems etc.